# "Don't you think?" vs "don't you think so"?

Tags: word-choice

> Life would be a lot less painful without love, **don't you think**?"
>
> Life would be a lot less painful without love, **don't you think so**?"

Do they mean the same? Or they have slightly different meanings?

Comment: "Don't you think?" sounds wrong (in AmE, I don't know about BrE or other). The native expectation is to always say "don't you think so?". That is, they have really different meanings because the first one doesn't have any meaning at all!

Comment: That is, in that context of making a statement and following it with "don't you ...?". If out of that context and if you're asking if someone is thinking at all, you can say "Don't you think?" meaning in general.

Comment: @Mitch: I disagree *in toto* (though from a BrE perspective). *Don't you think?* is a tag question here, and correct; *don't you think so? would be a run-on sentence, and so actually ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3):

> Life would be a lot less painful without love, don't you think?
>
> Life would be a lot less painful without love, don't you think so?

To some extent this might be a matter of opinion. However I'll give mine.

**1.** I would say that:

(a) 'don't you think?' is almost a throwaway line that seeks (and probably assumes) *confirmation* of the speaker's opinion.

(b) 'don't you think so?' is a request for information. It seeks the *opinion* of the listener.

**2.** I would expect a difference in intonation.

(c)  'don't you think?' would be unemphasised and take a descending tone.

(d) 'don't you think so?' would be stressed on the word 'think' and would have a rising tone towards 'think' followed by a descending tone afterwards.

**Note**

Intonation and stress are very important in such cases. The way you speak a tag question can change its effect quite strongly.

Comment: I would say that, absent a difference in intonation, there's no difference, though the "so" version would be more likely to be used when the question is not rhetorical.  (And of course, as any Minnesotan knows, the *proper* way to state the first sense is "Dontcha know?")

Comment: @HotLicks, so essentially you agree with me.  I'm not sure that English is *ever* spoken without intonation--except perhaps by speech synthesisers or by humans when imitating robots. That's one reason these 'difference in meaning' questions can be so tricky.

Comment: Yeah, and it's one of the biggest failings of IPA.

Comment: Let's invent an improved IPA! I thought of doing it with standard musical notation. However that doesn't deal with glides (maybe I should say glissando) or fractions of a semitone very well. Any suggestions as to how to implement it?

Comment: I think first one needs to actually study intonation.  There does not even seem to be much agreement as to what a "question" intonation is, one of the most basic of them.  (But, interestingly, one that does have an IPA notation of sorts: `?`.)